# angular module not working

Tags: angularjs, appjs

I am using angular.js. I have created app.js file where i entered the code as:

```
angular.module('polls', ['pollServices'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
     {
    $routeProvider
         .when('/polls', { templateUrl: 'partials/list.html', controller: PollListCtrl })
         .when('/poll/:pollId', { templateUrl: 'partials/item.html', controller: PollItemCtrl })
         .when('/new', { templateUrl: 'partials/new.html', controller: PollNewCtrl })
         .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/polls' });
}]);
```

but when i run the code, it gives the error as:

```
angular.module('polls', ['pollServices']
^
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Comment: add your custom js files after angular.js:)

Comment: can you please let me know the syntax, how can i add that :)

Comment: post your html file :)

Comment: In your index.html file when you include scripts, first include angular.js, then your app.js script.

Comment: i dont have index.html file in my project

Comment: Then you are doing something increadibly wrong, unless you have another html file named differently. How do you even run the app.js file without an html file?

Comment: I am new to this language. I am using the poll code which i got through the google search..

Answer (score 0):

Your main html file, normally index.html should look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="polls">
<head>
    <title>Website</title>

    <!--<script src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/libs/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="js/polls.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="mainController">
</body>

</html>
```

PS: Relating to your last comment AngularJS is not a language, but a JavaScript framework.